# Google Sheet App Script Excel File Download Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-excel, urlfetch

Once I Download the sent Excel Files from Gmail it shows data as per below Picture 2. I know there are Formulas on google sheet which it is copying as it is but doing problem while enabling the links.

Is there a Way i can Paste those as VALUES ONLY ? Instead of Pasting the Cell Formula?

Looking forward, thank you!

SHOULD BE LIKE THIS:
[image]

Once Enable Editing is done, HERE PROBLEM:
[image]

Below is the Code I am using to send all these files.

```
function sendExcelAttachmentsInOneEmail() {
  var sheets = ['Sheet 1', 'Sheet 2', 'Sheet 3', 'Sheet 4', 'Sheet 5', 'Sheet 6'];
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadSheetId = spreadSheet.getId();

  var urls = sheets.map(sheet => {
    var sheetId = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheet).getSheetId();
    return `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=${spreadSheetId}&gid=${sheetId}&exportFormat=xlsx`;
  });

  var reportName = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet 7').getRange(1, 13).getValue();

  var params = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var fileNames = ['Sheet 1.xlsx',
                   'Sheet 2.xlsx',
                   'Sheet 3.xlsx',
                   'Sheet 4.xlsx',
                   'Sheet 5.xlsx',
                   'Sheet 6.xlsx'];

  var blobs = urls.map((url, index) => {
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(fileNames[index]);
  });


  var message = {
    to: 'email@example.com',
    cc: 'emails@examples.com',
    subject: 'REPORTS - ' + reportName,
    body: "Hi Team,\n\nPlease find attached Reports.\n\nBest Regards!",
    attachments: blobs
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly replicate and understand your current situation, can you provide a sample XLSX file?

Comment: You need to use a different code. Instead of directly exporting Google spreadsheets to Excel you should create *something* holding only values. I.E. as the script creates single sheet spreadsheets you could export the sheets as  CSV instead of XLXS. Please show what you have tried to fix the issue by your self, including a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].